# Doing cumulative sums over multiple variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
Date <- c(rep("5/22/19", 3), rep("5/23/19", 3), rep("5/24/19", 3))
Source <- rep(c("Control", "A", "B"), 3)
ValueA <- c(12080, 12012, 11944, 13345, 13342, 13422, 16226, 16045, 16221)
ValueB <- c(11, 9, 13, 11, 9, 7, 12, 9, 15)
df <- tibble(Date, Source, ValueA, ValueB)

df
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Date    Source  ValueA ValueB
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 5/22/19 Control  12080     11
2 5/22/19 A        12012      9
3 5/22/19 B        11944     13
4 5/23/19 Control  13345     11
5 5/23/19 A        13342      9
6 5/23/19 B        13422      7
7 5/24/19 Control  16226     12
8 5/24/19 A        16045      9
9 5/24/19 B        16221     15
```

What I want is, cumulative sums by both `Date` **and** `Source`. So the output would look like:

```
  Date    Source  ValueA ValueB
1 5/22/19 Control  12080     11
2 5/22/19 A        12012      9
3 5/22/19 B        11944     13
4 5/23/19 Control  25425     22
5 5/23/19 A        25354     18
6 5/23/19 B        25366     20
7 5/24/19 Control  41651     34
8 5/24/19 A        41399     27
9 5/24/19 B        41587     35
```

However, when I use this code:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, Source) %>%
  summarize(
    ValueA = sum(ValueA, na.rm = TRUE),
    ValueB = sum(ValueB, na.rm = TRUE),
    Cum_A = cumsum(ValueA, na.rm = TRUE),
    Cum_B = cumsum(ValueB, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

I get the error

```
Error in cumsum(ValueA, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'cumsum' which requires 1
```

I assume the `cumsum` function is not designed to handle multiple grouping variables. So how do I get the result that I want?

Comment: It's not the grouping variable at all; just look at `?cumsum`, does it accept a `na.rm` argument?

Comment: Additionally, it's a little weird that you are `summarize`-ing with `cumsum`; typically that would be a `mutate`. You have a mix of things that will return either one value or a vector. That's not typically what one would do inside `summarize`, are you sure you meant to do that?

Comment: Yes, and he's right about `na.rm` also. I'm just saying, when I ask for help, it implies that I know I'm doing something wrong. You don't have to ask me how wrong that I think I am.

Comment: I asked if that was what you intended because sometimes (a lot of the times, frankly) when people ask for help sometimes they copy & paste code incorrectly into their question and introduce things that look like errors that are in fact not something they are trying to do. And then they'll yell at you for pointing it out. So I was trying to _ask_ to verify if that was really what you meant, or if perhaps you'd just included some code you didn't intend (the `sum`s).

Comment: But I can see that you don't really want help from me, so I'll just move on. Good luck, I hope you sort it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use `group_by(Source)`. See if this does what you are looking for.

Some notes:

- It is optional to keep `Source` in `arrange()`; removing it will recreate the data you asked for above. I am including it so the `cumsum()` result is more obvious
- Given your current dataset (no dupes of `Source` or `Date`), aggregation isn't required and `mutate()` will do the trick
- `cumsum()` doesn't take a `na.rm` argument but you can substitute a 0 with `replace_na()`

```r
df <- 
  tibble(
    Date = rep(c("5/22/19", "5/23/19", "5/24/19"), each = 3),
    Source = rep(c("Control", "A", "B"), 3), 
    ValueA = c(12080, 12012, 11944, 13345, 13342, 13422, 16226, 16045, 16221), 
    ValueB = c(11, 9, 13, NA, 9, 7, 12, 9, 15)
  )


df %>%  
  arrange(Source, Date) %>% 
  group_by(Source) %>%
  mutate(
    Cum_A = cumsum(replace_na(ValueA, 0)),
    Cum_B = cumsum(replace_na(ValueB, 0))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Date    Source  ValueA ValueB Cum_A Cum_B
# 5/22/19 A        12012      9 12012     9
# 5/23/19 A        13342      9 25354    18
# 5/24/19 A        16045      9 41399    27
# -----------------------------------------
# 5/22/19 B        11944     13 11944    13
# 5/23/19 B        13422      7 25366    20
# 5/24/19 B        16221     15 41587    35
# -----------------------------------------
# 5/22/19 Control  12080     11 12080    11
# 5/23/19 Control  13345     NA 25425    11
# 5/24/19 Control  16226     12 41651    34
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the sort of answer I was looking for with my complaints above.